# jQuery.get() div html data from external page

Tags: jquery, get, jquery-load

When we use jQuery `load()` we can define a DIV on the external page we want to load into our content.

Is there a similar way to get the html data from a specific DIV from an external page?
Something like this?

```
var url = someurl;
var div = specificdiv
    $.get(someurl+' '+specificdiv , function(data) {
        $('#target_div').html(data);
    });
```

Comment: This is a job for AJAX!  Although not sure if you'll have issues with cross-domain urls.  BTW: this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496491/jquery-ajax-success-function-not-rendering-html-with-jquery-ui-elements

Comment: Thanks. That was quick. Update my question shortly.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#target').load('http://example.com/someurl.html #specificdiv');
```